# Can't find a way to exit loop and keep the currently entered variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def active_check(active):
    for i in range(0, (len(active_data)-1)):
        if active == active_data[i][0]:
            raise active_Cert
            break
        else:
            print("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT")
    return active

try:
    while True:
        active = active_check(input("Enter state"))
except active_Cert:
    pass
print(active)
```

I have this set up, where the user enters a number and then it scans through a CSV to find if that number matches any of the data in the 1st 'column'. If it finds one then it should raise an exception which quits the while loop the function is in - and it does. The problem is that the final print statement prints the second to last entered variable (given that there were multiple incorrect entries)

I can see why this is, although I can't find a good way to get around it

Comment: The value of `active` is not returned as you raise the exception. You could return it as a `value` part of the exception if you wanted to, but at a first glance, you probably don't need to raise the exception in `active_check`. You could simply `return active` instead of `raise` and `return None` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible solution is to return some variable with `active` variable instead of throwing an exception.**

Consider this code, I added `to_continue` variable and removed an exception part:

```
def active_check(active):
    for i in range(0, (len(active_data)-1)):
        if active == active_data[i][0]:
            return active, False
        else:
            print("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT")
    return active, True

to_continue = True
while to_continue:
    active, to_continue = active_check(input("Enter state"))
print(active)
```